# SharePoint 2007 - custom context menu for certain file types

Tags: 2007, editing-menu

I was wondering if someone could help me out with SharePoint 2007. What I want to do is to add a custom menu item to a context menu (the menu that opens when you click a document or another item).

Right now, the menu looks like this: [picture](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/4867/menu1vt.png)

I want to add an item, "Do stuff" for example, to this menu. Major problems:

1. I wish this item to appear only in menus for a certain file type (e.g. only for .html but not for .doc);
2. When I click this item ("Do stuff"), I want to call custom external code (written in C#, either an exe or a DLL), which accepts the name of the clicked file as an input parameter.

I understand the way to achieve this is by using Custom Actions (no JavaScript editing required in 2007, right?). But since I'm quite new to MOSS, I'm a bit lost and not sure what exactly to do and where to start, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a feature that includes your custom action and some code to execute.

Here is a walk-through:  http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2008/08/11/SharePoint-2007-Deployment_3A00_-Custom-Action-Features.aspx